# Google Chrome doesn't print to Google Drive. In my Gloogle Cloud Print I don't have Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, google-cloud-print

Instead of having "Save to Google Drive" like they say here: https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/2541913?hl=en&ref_topic=4456182

in my Chrome 48.0.2564.82 m (64-bit) there isn't this link in my printers. Why not? I have to reset something in my browser, in my Drive, in my Cloud Print? I don't have "Google Drive printer" in my Google Cloud Print. Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be a U.S.-only thing. Based on the language I see above (Italian?) I'm guessing you're outside the U.S. This is only a guess at a possibility, however.

Comment: FWIW I don't see that option either (UK).

Comment: What to do so? I have to change my language? From where?

Comment: Are you using a regular Google account, or a Google Apps account?

Comment: Regular Google account. Why?

Comment: Just that if you were using a Google Apps account, this might be a setting controlled by the administrator. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. The only thing that seems to jive is that it's not available in your country, but I can't find any information online that this feature is country-restricted.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

According to david.king in this [answer](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/MVPqixERhQQ/r2A0j2bUAwAJ) on Jan 27, 2016 in a thread to a similar question in the Chrome Help Product Forums the issue was resolved.

## Explanation

It looks that issue was related to the related Chrome version as several users in had the same problem. The issue was escalated and fixed a couple of days later. See the "full history" in [Missing Save to Google Drive from print menu](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/MVPqixERhQQ)